# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ddl, ora-00907

**What could be the problem?**

```
CREATE TABLE ASIGNACION_ANUAL(
ANIO NUMBER(4),
COD_VENDEDOR VARCHAR2(4),
MONTO_ASIGNACION NUMBER(9) NULL_MONTO,
CANT_VENTAS NUMBER(2) NULL_CANT_VENTAS,
CONSTRAINT ASIGNACION_ANUAL_PK PRIMARY KEY (ANIO, COD_VENDEDOR)
);
```

Error message:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: @Hadi: please do not add the PLSQL if the question is not about PL/SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove NULL_MONTO and NULL_CANT_VENTAS :

```
CREATE TABLE ASIGNACION_ANUAL (
ANIO NUMBER(4),
COD_VENDEDOR VARCHAR2(4),
MONTO_ASIGNACION NUMBER(9) NULL,
CANT_VENTAS NUMBER(2) NULL,
CONSTRAINT ASIGNACION_ANUAL_PK PRIMARY KEY (ANIO, COD_VENDEDOR)
)
```